# Dynamic Data Masking performance in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem:** We were able to implement Dynamic Data Masking in Snowflake. The pattern we follow for explicit fields (normal fields) is: Masking Policy + UDF. The masking policy evaluates the user's role and applies (or not) the masking through the UDF.
Now, let's assume the table where we are implemented the masking has 100 Millions recs. The Q is, how many times the UDF runs? This 100% related to performance and potential impact as the table grows over time.

**We've tried**: We ran multiple test and examined the profile and see that Snowflake rewrites the columns like this: Masking-Policy-Name(Field-Name). What it's not clear is whether or not it evaluates the masking policy (and thus, the UDF) for EVERY single record in the table.

Looking forward to seeing your feedback!
Thanks
Leo

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it only runs the UDF on rows in your result set for a given query, not necessarily the whole table. However, I can't find specific documentation to back that up at the moment.

Comment: You could do some testing to figure this out though. Create an inefficient UDF and see how it runs on a SELECT TOP 1 vs. SELECT TOP 100000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake will only execute the MPs on the result set (there are some very specific circumstances where this may not be the case but you are unlikely to encounter them).

However, I’m wondering why you are implementing your MPs using UDFs? Given that using MPs will always have a performance impact, it makes sense to keep them as simple as possible and the fact you are using UDFs suggests you are implementing some complex logic (or else why use UDFs?).

Comment: Thanks for the input. For structured fields you are correct, it's all about complex logics. However, if you have to mask attributes within Json, you end up building a UDF (if you have any other approach let me know). That's why it's important to understand the impact and how Snowflake does the masking + udf. Looking at the query plan it seems it applies the mp and udf to the result set.

Comment: Ok. Applying MPs to JSON is (in most circumstances) a really bad idea. Just because Snowflake allows you to query json with SQL doesn’t mean you should leave your data in this format. Ideally, you should extract your data out into proper relational structures and then apply MPs to that

Comment: Yup, I totally understand your point. In particular, the client I work for has most of its data in Json format. I found this link that explains how to mask Json attributes with masking policies and UDF. https://www.snowflake.com/blog/masking-semi-structured-data-with-snowflake/

Comment: @LeonardoTizón Were you able to solve the performance issue? I am also facing the same where i am masking multiple nested attributes of JSON data using UDF which simply updates the JPATH directly. Running select is taking alot of time. OBJECT_INSERT is performing better but to update multiple attributes in the same JSON that too nested is very complex using OBJECT_INSERT. Are you trying out something different?

Comment: One performance constraint I've noticed with the dynamic masking is that it passes the entire variant to the UDF. So, you lose any columnar optimizations when selecting one field or more from the variant and the problem becomes row-bound.